# Catch user-e-mail with facebook login / Permission already set

Tags: facebook, email, authentication, facebook-login

I am working on a facebook login issue here. As far as the facebook developer documentation goes I was able to find how to ask for the permission. Now I do ask the user for his permission for me to acess his e-mail but I still cant find a way to actually get the mail-adress for storing it in a database.

I would guess there is a simple solution so I would be glad if anyone could help me out here very quick..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have permission for something, it is really easy. **You just make requests to facebook**.

I will show you, how to do that via `FB PHP SKD` && `Graph API`.

```
try {
    $email = $your_fb_object->api('/me?fields=email', 'GET');


}
catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    //api call has not been successful, deal with an error, e.g. log it…
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Code place whereever after initiation of the FB object.

As for documentation, check simple [`FB tutorial`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/).